# How to display next 5 days in php

Tags: php, timestamp, date

How would i display the next 5 days in php?

18/03/2012

19/03/2012

20/03/2012

21/03/2012

22/03/2012

Comment: Try using the `date` function, you can pass in a `$timestamp` parameter which is the number of seconds since jan 1st 1970, good luck :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
    echo date("d/m/Y", time() + 86400 * $i) . "<br>";
```

Comment: Again, there's a small potential here for issues around DST transitions.  Once a year, the day is 25 hours long, right?

Comment: Technically the day is still 24 hours long, the clock just repeats the same hour twice when it gets there. I actually tried testing and it seems to handle it ok in every situation. Fun fact: Win 7 won't allow you to set the time if the new time is in the DST transition

Answer (score 3):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+'.$i.' day')) ."<br />";
}
```

Comment: you probably need to use the `$i` variable inside the loop right..?

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    var_dump(date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+ $i days")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this:

```
$cursor=new DateTime("now",new DateTimeZone("America/Chicago"));

for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
    $cursor->modify("+1 day");
    echo "\n".$cursor->format("d/m/Y");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$day = 60 * 60 * 24;
$today = time();

for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
{
    echo date("d/m/Y", $today + $day * $i) + "\n";
}
```

Comment: There might be a risk here of oddities surrounding daylight savings time transitions.

Comment: True, but the OP didn't seem concerned with that sort of thing.  I didn't set a timezone either.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$dt = new DateTime();
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $dt->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    echo $dt->format('d/m/Y'), "\n\n";
}
```